# Excel vba remove tooltip if cell blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba that when I click in a cell (that contains "ID's" it searches in another sheet for that "ID" and creates a tooltip with information from that sheet. It's working good as follows:

- If ID exists, shows the tooltip when I click it. Hides tooltip if I click in an empty cell;
- If the ID does not exists, it shows nothing;

My problem remains in the follow step:

- If I had an ID that exists and remove it from the cell, the tooltip remains there but without information. Each time I click in that cell, it shows the empty tooltip. I need it to not show anything like the cell is empty.

My Code:

```
Public sTarget As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

sTarget = Target.Address

Dim MyVal As String
Dim MyToolTipBody As String
Dim MyToolTipHead As String
Dim Rng As String

On Error Resume Next
MyVal = "*" & Range(sTarget).Value
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
On Error Resume Next
    Rng = .Cells.Find(What:=MyVal, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Address
    MyToolTipHead = 'Code for tooltip header
    MyToolTipBody = 'Code for tooltip body
End With

With Range(sTarget).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = MyToolTipHead
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = MyToolTipBody
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = False
End With
End Sub
```

Any suggestions in how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Rather than skipping over errors (not good practice anyway), check if the value is found (Not Nothing) and only show the tip if it is found.

Comment: Also perhaps you should use SelectionChange.

Comment: But if I try to use "If Not MyVal Is Nothing Then" I keep getting "Type mismatch" error.@SJR could you please elaborate the use of SelectionChange?

Comment: You say you have code that works when "I click in a cell" but that is what SelectionChange does. You are using Change which is only activated when you change a cell. Is that what you want? Re Find, you need to assign a range object to the Find operation and check if that's nothing (you don't actually appear to use `Rng`).

Comment: I just use rng it to search in a cell. I don't use it later because it's only used to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two options for you:

1. Detect a cell becomes empty ("") using a Worksheet_change event and delete validation to remove tooltip
2. Use your current Select event but introduce an IF block to say "If the cell is empty, then remove validation, otherwise create a tooltip..." to ensure validation (and therefore your tooltip) is deleted when you click on a blank cell.

I think the best is definitely Option 1.  I've included Option 2 just so you can see how it can be done with just your current event and how that logically follows on to using Worksheet_change for the tooltip removal instead.

**Option 1**

Add a worksheet change event that does this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.value = "" Then
      Target.Validation.Delete
   End If

End Sub
```

This will trigger when you delete your ID from a cell; then your Target.Value will equal "" and thus any validation will be deleted automatically too; taking away the tooltip.

The unintended consquence is that this removes *all* validation; so if you want to keep certain other validation (like data type, List) you will have to re-add it to the cell; you could write a subroutine for just this (e.g. sub putValidationBack(x_in as Range).. )

**Option 2**

Add an IF block around your current code:

```vb
if Range(sTarget).Value = "" then
   With Range(sTarget).Validation
      .Delete
   End with
Else
  ' Everything after and including your On Error Resume goes here

End if
```

Same consquence as above this will remove all validation so you'll need to put back any validation you want to keep.